# I wanted to create video streaming website, but the problem that I want to hard sub

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, watermark, subtitle

I want to hardsub all the movies and add watermark to them, I used ffmpeg once bu it’s slow, if you can recommend new way or how to use it faster.

Comment: This will most likely end up being closed, as software recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to find something on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange site, but please keep in mind [what topics you can post about there](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log so we can make suggestions. Right now your question has no details so we can't provide any answers.

Answer (score 0):

To use a hardsub and watermark you will need to transcoding the entire movie. It is a slow operation regardless the software you use.

Maybe you can think about use a subtitle track. Watermarks can be used on players side too. That way you won't need transcoding.